# JavaFX WebView not rendering - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, webview

I've been trying to copy a JavaFX Eclipse project into a newly created IntelliJ idea project, but I keep getting this error that I don't understand:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()'
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPageBackBufferImpl.validate(WCPageBackBufferImpl.java:99)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:703)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:579)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()'
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPageBackBufferImpl.validate(WCPageBackBufferImpl.java:99)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:703)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:579)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()'
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPageBackBufferImpl.validate(WCPageBackBufferImpl.java:99)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:703)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:579)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()'
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPageBackBufferImpl.validate(WCPageBackBufferImpl.java:99)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:703)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:579)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()'
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPageBackBufferImpl.validate(WCPageBackBufferImpl.java:99)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:703)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:579)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

I don't see any of my classes there so I don't know what's happening. It just shows a blank window.
Any ideas on what the problem might be? I think I've already added all the maven dependencies.

Apparently it only happens when I have this simple webview in my .FXML file:

```
 <WebView fx:id="svgWebView" prefHeight="452.0" prefWidth="338.0" />
```

Comment: Maybe a version incompatibility between `javafx.web` and your other JavaFX modules?

Comment: The `com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()` method was added in this [commit](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/commit/73e70fe978dda9fc821061dfc12bfb742dd7dc25#diff-b31000c8c3e12dbd000fafd25e6c793ec350784d5577d468fc9b81f67f90571bL35) as part of [a fix](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8239589) which was implemented for JavaFX 17.  Make sure that all your code is using only JavaFX 17 modules. Run your application with the argument `--list-modules`. All `javafx.*` modules should be `@17`.  Ensure JavaFX is not being run from the classpath.

Comment: getting same error when I load any html to webview via [this fxml](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/swaggerific/blob/main/src/main/resources/com/mascix/swaggerific/edit/settings/About.fxml) with [this backend](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/swaggerific/blob/main/src/main/java/com/mascix/swaggerific/ui/edit/About.java#L16) code. All javafx dependecies uses same version, @Maxim any chance did you find a solution for this ?